# Title Page with TikZ that fits on A4 Paper Size

Tags: tikz-pgf, titles, paper-size

Using the following TikZ code or background image, I would like to add some information to it and use as my title page such that it fits perfectly on an A4 paper size.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\shadedraw [left color=red,right color=blue] (0,0) rectangle (10,13);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I would like to add:

1. My book's title centered around the top: "This is my Book's Title" in white text.
2. Then below that the author, also centered and in white: "Author XY". I am using the standard book class.
3. And finally down below the date also in white and centered.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would suggest looking into [`tikzpagenodes`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikzpagenodes)...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Werner. I succeeded in getting the background image fill the whole page a with the code below: \thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay] 
{%
  %\draw [blue,line width=2mm](current page.south west)rectangle (current page.north east);
  \shadedraw [top color=red,bottom color=blue] (current page.south west) rectangle (current page.north east); 
}% 
\end{tikzpicture}.     But how can I add my information as mentioned above?

Comment: But when I add the following lines in the above code: \draw [green]
(current page text area.south west) rectangle
(current page text area.north east); I get an error saying No shape named current page text area is known? Did I miss something?

Comment: @DavesBroadley dis you load the package,  `\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}`?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina thanks. That's exactly what I was missing. I thought the nodes are provided in the tikz package when I use 'remember picture' and 'overlay' as options. I did not know I also have to include the tikzpagenodes package. Thanks

Comment: @DavesBroadley You're welcome. The "current page" nodes are provided by `TikZ`; the "current page text area" nodes are provided by `tikzpagenodes`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have to do everything with `tikz`. In fact, it is not advisable. Draw the shaded region with `tikz` and type every thing else using `titlepage` environment. This way you get more control.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1in]{geometry}
\begin{document}
  \begin{titlepage}
    \centering  \sffamily
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \shade [top color=red,bottom color=blue] (current page.south west) rectangle (current page.north east); 
  \end{tikzpicture}
  {\Huge\textcolor{white}{This is my book'stitle}}
  \par\vspace{0.5in}
  {\large \textcolor{white}{This is my subtitle}}
  \par\vspace{\stretch{1}}
  {\Large \textcolor{white}{Author XY}}
  \par
  \vfill
  \textcolor{white}{\today} 
\end{titlepage}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much Harish Kumar for the solution and advice. It fits perfectly like magic. @jesse thank you also. Harish Kumar's worked well for me. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 6):

Would this be what you seek? Here a solution defines node A and B at `current page.south west` and `current page.north east`, respectively. Write those three lines respectivley at `current page.north, current page.center and current page.south`. Actually, current page node notion is an absolute position, one can add option `[xshift=<dim>,yshift=<dim>]` to place a node anywhere in the page and write text. For example,

```
\node [yshift=-3cm,text=white] at (current page.north){\large \sf This is a subtitle};
```

will add a subtitle right below the book title.

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty} % \pagestyle command corrected
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node (A) at (current page.south west){};
\node (B) at (current page.north east){};
\shade [top color=red,bottom color=blue] (A) rectangle (B);

\node  [yshift=-2cm,text=white] at (current page.north){\Huge \sf This is my book'stitle};
\node [yshift=-3cm,text=white] at (current page.north){\large \sf This is a subtitle};

\node [text=white] at (current page.center){\Large \sf Author XY};

\node [yshift=2cm,text=white] at (current page.south){\today};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why use _four_ `tikzpicture`? One is enough...

Comment: To remove the page number, you may use the `titlepage` environment.

Comment: To remove the black border around the background, use `\shade` (or `\fill`) instead of `\shadedraw`.

Comment: @PaulGaborit -- Thanks for the comments, I did observe those to improve my post, working on it and my internet is giving me trouble now. Yes. one tikzpicture is enough, but I was considering 3 areas to write text, trying to code in 3 sections for easy of debugging.